# LDAP authentication of user by application user

Tags: authentication, ldap

I am new to LDAP authentication. I want to authenticate the users with their LDAP credentials.
For that I got the application credential from server so that I can authenticate other users.

My credential as application user are as:

```
Test LDAP Server IP: xx.xx.xx.xx
Port: 389
Bind DN:uid=uidxx,ou=applications,dc=dcxx
password: passxx
```

For authenticating the this user, I have written the code as

```
public String ldap()
{
        String value=null;
        SearchControls constraints= new SearchControls();
        Hashtable<String, String> env= new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"uid=uidxx, ou=applications, dc=dcxx");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"passxx");

        try {
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            value = "Done with it";

        } 
        catch(AuthenticationException e)
        {
            value = "Invalid User name or password";
        }
        catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            value = "Exception occurred";

        }

        return value;
    }
```

I got return value as `"Done with it"`

Now i want to authenticate other user whose mail id and password is known to me.
Its like i want authenticate other users using their mailid, password, and for that i got uidxx and passxx to authenticate them.
How should i do that?

Not getting much help from the other sources.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When authenticating against LDAP common work flow is

1. Bind to LDAP using credentials you have. This user have to have at least read-only access to subtree with users. Often it is ou=People, ou=Domain, dc=com or similar.
2. Query LDAP server for user's DN (here is where ANR might be useful)
3. Try to bind to LDAP using user's DN and password supplied to your application

This works because it is very common to give every user RW rights to his object in database. Very useful if you want user to be able to change their own password.

Comment: Thanks tomas789. I have read only access to data base server. My credential are uidxx, passxx and applications as mentioned in question. Now these credential are for authenticating me so that ican authenticate other users with thier mail id and password. I am getting success in authenticating me by above code. Now i want to authenticate others in my application. How should i do that?

Comment: @Optimus I'm quite sure I have answered this. In step 1 as I mentioned above you bind using YOUR credentials and in step 3 you bind using USER's credentials. If it succeeded user supplied valid credentials otherwise he did not. Steps 1 and 2 are only necessary to get user's DN (not yours) if you already know this you can directly jump to step 3 (this is not very often specially when user supplied email address or name or something like this)